# What if ammonia is used as a refrigerant for a refrigerator?

Tags: heat-transfer, refrigeration

I have a refrigerator whose compressor configuration is:

power- 10hp

compression ratio- 10:1

I do not have expertise in this field, but I am curious if I use ammonia as a refrigerant instead of HFC-134a then what will be the temperature in the hot side of the refrigerator?

Comment: Ammonia has been used in refrigeration - do some research.

Comment: Not enough clarity or details. Try reading up here first and see if this helps you form more  ideas so that your question can be asked better: https://theengineeringmindset.com/industrial-refrigeration-basics/
(There are loads of other options too)

Comment: https://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=337162

This MIGHT be what you're looking for, round-a-bout. Lowest cold side temp is -60F for an Ammonia system. That's not what you're asking, but it really is about the best that can be done.